# Error in numbering equations

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\intertext{Removing the K factor, Eqn.  turn into the classical CORDIC Equations}
\label{Equ. 3.14}
x_{i+1}=[x_i-y_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i] \\
\label{Equ. 3.15}
 y_{i+1}=[y_i+x_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i] \\
 \intertext{Considering the aim of the CORDIC algorithm is to rotate a vector V(x, y) to unit vector (1, 0), the direction of each rotation can be decided by $y_{i+1}$ or the angle accumulator, which is defined as $Z_{i+1}$.  Since $y_{i+1}$  would finally be 0, via Equ., the direction of rotation could be defined as:}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
\label{equ: 3.16}
d_i =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    +1  & \mbox{if } y_i < 0  \\
    -1 & \mbox{if }  y_i \geq 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

For some unknown reason i am getting an extra equation number 3 in between as below:-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\intertext` is for text between equations, but the next equation after the second `\intertext` is empty.
The following example moves the last equation to the `gather` environment.
Also environment `cases` is used instead of the manual `array` construct:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\intertext{Removing the $K$ factor, Eqn.\@ turn into the classical CORDIC
Equations}
\label{Equ. 3.14}
x_{i+1}=[x_i-y_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i] \\
\label{Equ. 3.15}
 y_{i+1}=[y_i+x_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i] \\
\intertext{Considering the aim of the CORDIC algorithm is to rotate a
vector $V(x, y)$ to unit vector $(1, 0)$, the direction of each rotation can be
decided by $y_{i+1}$ or the angle accumulator, which is defined as
$Z_{i+1}$.  Since $y_{i+1}$  would finally be 0, via Equ., the direction of
rotation could be defined as:}
\label{equ: 3.16}
d_i =
\begin{cases}
    +1 & \mbox{if } y_i < 0  \\
    -1 & \mbox{if } y_i \geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I would remove the first instance of `\intertext`, i.e., have the `gather` environment start *after* the opening sentence. If nothing else, doing so will give TeX to find another suitable page break, if need be.

Comment: @Mico I had considered this, but I do not know, if this is out of context and the real document contains an equation before. Also preventing the page break before equation one might be on purpose.

Comment: There will never be a page break just before `equation`.

Comment: @egreg Unless there is an empty line between the text and the equation.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That's an error. I'm talking of correct input. Your code makes a very big object that can't be split, which is wrong, in my opinion. There would be nothing bad in splitting the middle paragraph across pages.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `\intertext`. There's no need whatsoever for it in this case, because its purpose is to have text between *alignment displays*, but neither `gather` nor `equation` do any sort of alignment: they just center the equations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

Removing the $K$ factor, Eqn.  turn into the classical CORDIC Equations
\begin{gather}
\label{Equ. 3.14}
x_{i+1}=[x_i-y_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i] \\
\label{Equ. 3.15}
 y_{i+1}=[y_i+x_i \cdot 2^{-i}\cdot d_i]
\end{gather}
Considering the aim of the CORDIC algorithm is to rotate a vector $V(x, y)$ to unit vector 
$(1, 0)$, the direction of each rotation can be decided by $y_{i+1}$ or the angle 
accumulator, which is defined as $Z_{i+1}$.  Since $y_{i+1}$ would finally be 0, via 
Equ., the direction of rotation could be defined as:
\begin{equation}
\label{equ: 3.16}
d_i =
\begin{cases}
    +1 & \text{if $y_i < 0$}  \\
    -1 & \text{if $y_i \geq 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Note also the use of `cases` and how math should always properly be segregated: for instance, it must be `$V(x, y)$`.

[image]

By the way, the wrong equation number follows from the `\\` preceding `\intertext`. There should *never* be a trailing `\\` in `amsmath` environment such as `align`. `alignat`, `gather`, `multline`.